# Sonatype Nexus Login Issue via Private Ingress Controller in EKS Cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks, nexus, sonatype, nexus3

I have deployed a Sonatype Nexus application in my EKS cluster, and it is configured with several local users and roles. Additionally, I have set up two ingress controllers using the nginx Ingress controller Helm chart: one public ingress controller and one private ingress controller. The public ingress controller creates a Classic Load Balancer in my AWS environment. The nexus is being served through these ingress controllers.

Here's the problem I'm facing: The Sonatype Nexus login works perfectly when served through the public ingress controller. However, when I attempt to log in using the same user credentials through the private ingress controller, it shows an error stating "incorrect username or password" or "no permission to use the application" in the Nexus UI.

I have checked the Nexus pod logs, and it indicates that the user session is created. Despite that, I cannot log in through the private ingress controller.

Troubleshooting Steps Taken So Far:

I have verified the correctness of the user credentials, ensuring that I am using the correct username and password.

I compared the configurations of both the public and private ingress controllers, ensuring that they are similar.

I checked the annotations of the private ingress controller's service and verified that they are set correctly, including the SSL certificates, SSL negotiation policies, and SSL ports.

I confirmed that DNS resolution is properly set up, allowing the private ingress controller to resolve the Nexus server's hostname.

I inspected the security group rules associated with the Nexus server and the private ingress controller, ensuring that the necessary ports are open for communication.

I checked the Nexus configuration, especially authentication and security settings, to ensure they are correctly configured.

I monitored the logs of both the Nexus server and the private ingress controller, but no errors or warnings related to the login failures were found.
My Assumptions:

There could be a network or connectivity issue between the private ingress controller and the Nexus server, but I am unsure how to verify this.
There might be certificate trust issues with the private ingress controller, but I am not certain how to validate this assumption.

I would appreciate any guidance or additional troubleshooting steps to help resolve this issue.